# Related rates: derivative of the function $A = \frac{x\cdot y}{2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Doing a related rates exercise, suppose you have this area formula for a triangle:

$$A = \frac{x \cdot y}{2}$$

Where $A$, $x$ and $y$ are all functions with respect to time. I have to calculate the derivative.

The derivative of $A$ would be just $1 \cdot \frac{dA}{t}$.

But what of $$\frac{x\cdot y}{2}$$?

Do I apply the product rule? So it would be

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot \frac{y}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{x}{2}$$

?

Comment: derivative w.r.t. $t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to the same idea as was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520010/help-understand-related-rates-problem-calculating-the-derivative-of-the-distanc): use [the chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

We have
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
You should be able to figure it out, given that
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}=\frac{y}{2},\quad\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{2}$$

---

Another way to do it in this case is to use the product rule, where $f(t)=x(t)$ and $f'(t)=x'(t)$, and $g(t)=y(t)$ and $g'(t)=y'(t)$.

Comment: I don't quite see why are you multiplying $\frac{dx}{dt}$ by $\frac{dA}{dx}$. Why $\frac{dA}{dx}$?

Comment: @ZolTunKul Think about some function $f(x)$, where $x=x(t)$. Using the chain rule,$$\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}t}=f'(x)\cdot x'(t)$$This is the same thing, just with two variables. Alternatively, use the product rule, where $f(t)=x(t)$ and $f'(t)=x'(t)$, and $g(t)=y(t)$ and $g'(t)=y'(t)$.

Comment: What's the problem with my attempt at the product rule though?

Comment: @ZolTunKul You simply multiplied the whole thing by $\frac{1}{2}$ one extra time. I'm not sure why that happened.

Comment: Hmm... But if I have $\frac{x}{2}$, whose derivative is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$, by the product rule I have to multiply this by the $\frac{y}{2}$ (it's the other side of the product) which results in $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\frac{y}{2}$$.

Comment: @ZolTunKul Ah, but the product rule formula I gave already takes into account the $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hm, I just confirmed that I have an extra $\frac{1}{2}$ there. But I don't really get it because the derivative of $\frac{x}{2}$ is definitely $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}$ and then multiplied by the second part of the product, which is $\frac{y}{2}$.

Comment: @ZolTunKul Try taking out the $\frac{1}{2}$, and then doing the product rule. I think the problem here is that you multiply by $y$. One function is $\frac{x}{2}$, while the other is just $y$ - not $\frac{1}{2}$. I think that's what tripped you up.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly it. I had interpreted $$\frac{x\cdot y}{2} = \frac{x}{2}\cdot\frac{y}{2}$$  when it should've been $$\frac{x\cdot y}{2}  = \frac{x}{2} \cdot y$$
Thank you.